# Add product category of current product in custom field programmatically at the time of order in woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to add product category of current product in custom field at the time of order in woocommerce ?

Comment: But the product can have multiple category itself and even after order you can get those categories ! then why to save again ?

Comment: How can i get that categories in order object in wp? Do you know this?

Answer (score 0):

In order object you have function get_items(). then loop through items and then

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($id_product,'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
$cat_id = (int)$term_list[0];
echo get_term_link ($cat_id, 'product_cat');
```

'$id_product' pass item id here.

Comment: Not working in my theme and new version of woocommerce.